# “UNC paths are not supported” error in “SVN Info” command

Tags: java, windows, svn, cmd, unc

I am trying to run the command:

`cmd.exe /X /C "svn --non-interactive info <file name>`

by using `commandline.class` from the API (org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli)  which is called by
`SVNInfoCommand.class(org.apache.maven.scm.provider.svn.svnexe.command.info)`

It works fine when I pass a filename which exists in C:\ drive. 
But it returns the following error when I pass a filename which exists in shared location or network drive.  Error: "UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory. svn: '.' is not a working copy"

Current working directory is being set using the method `setWorkingDirectory( String path )`, but I suspect working directory is not being set when we use shared locations(UNC Paths).

> EX: \Test_Location\Test_File

This command works fine when I pass the “absolute path” of filename located in shared drive.

> (\Test_Location\Test_File)

Please let me know why we get this error when we use UNC paths even after setting the working directory.

Answer (score 5):

By default, the Windows command processor (`cmd.exe`) doesn't support `UNC` paths.

You can alter this behavior by adding a dedicated registry key, as described in [Microsoft KB 156276](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/156/Q156276/).

Alternatively, you can map your UNC path to a standard drive letter, and then use that.